# About CPP Files and Headers

Tags: c++, header

I'm learning C++ nowadays. Here is my question:
Can other people use any class member function we've defined even if they don't have our cpp file ? Detailed answers will be better. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking that if all they have is the header file can they still use the class if the implementation is in a separate cpp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ language standard says nothing about how code is or should be physically distributed in files, if, indeed, the code *is* stored in files.

In particular the standard library headers are not necessarily physical files, even if most implementations provide these headers as files.

Implementation files and header files are a convention, but only that, for physical packaging of code, with header files designed for inclusion via preprocessor `#include` directives, and implementation files designed for separate compilation. Usually an implementation file, like a .cpp file, therefore corresponds to a *translation unit* in the standard. But in some cases other physical source code packaging ideas are used, e.g. implementation files designed for inclusion in other implementation files.

The implementation of a function can be placed in an implementation file or in a header file, or e.g. in a database, the standard doesn't care. However, due to the way source code files are intended to be used, if the implementation is placed in a header file, and is not a template, then it should be `inline` so that it can occur in two or more translation units where that header is included. If the implementation-in-a-header is directly within a class definition then it's automatically `inline`, and otherwise it needs to be explicitly declared `inline`.

Now, if a user has the implementation source code, then the function can presumably be used.

Likewise, if the user has a declaration of the function plus a suitable compiled version, then likewise it can be used.

If the user doesn't have source or compiled version of the implementation, then it cannot be used.

So, this does not have very much to do with the files. But there is the aspect of whether you can distribute code without implementation files. And as discussed above, yes, you can, and that's often called **header only modules**.

Mainly, header only modules can do everything that ordinary separately compiled code can do, with one exception: they can't provide a “compiler firewall” to contain the symbols provided by a header.

And this leads to two main problems: (1) pollution of namespaces, and (2) inability to provide (without rewriting and awkward solutions) two modules whose implementations depend on each others declarations.

However, much code is distributed as header only modules. In particular large parts of the Boost library are header only modules. The main advantage is that for use of these parts there's no complication of building the library or fitting separately compiled code built with different options, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation of these functions is  inside the CPP file no they can't.
If the header file .h or .hpp contains the definition and implementation then yes they can.

Answer (score 0):

> Can other people use any class member function we've defined even if they don't have our cpp file?

Yes, as long you deliver a library containing your compiled `.cpp` file, and it fits for their compiler ABI, they will be able to use your code even without needing to compile the `.cpp` files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, if you build a library, and distribute it with your headers. People can then link to your library to use the functions and classes declared in your header files. The library will contain the code from your cpp files in binary, and the headers will guide the users' compilers on how to call the code in the library.

Here's documentation for Windows, and a tutorial for Linux:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html